# How to call db.Collection.stats() from Mongo java driver using MongoClient class

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I am using this dependency.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Package:

**package com.mongodb.MongoClient;**

How can I get collection by name then get its status so that the following information will be available:

1. size
2. storageSize

[Collection Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDtgK.png)

It seems that the answer for this [How to call db.Collection.stats() from Mongo java driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31043391/how-to-call-db-collection-stats-from-mongo-java-driver) uses deprecated class **package com.mongodb;**

```java
        // Mongodb initialization parameters.
        int port_no = 27017;
        String auth_user="jcg", auth_pwd = "admin@123", host_name = "localhost", db_name = "mongoauthdemo", db_col_name = "emp", encoded_pwd = "";

        /* Imp. Note -
         *      1.  Developers will need to encode the 'auth_user' or the 'auth_pwd' string if it contains the <code>:</code> or the <code>@</code> symbol. If not, the code will throw the <code>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException</code>.
         *      2.  If the 'auth_user' or the 'auth_pwd' string does not contain the <code>:</code> or the <code>@</code> symbol, we can skip the encoding step.
         */
        try {
            encoded_pwd = URLEncoder.encode(auth_pwd, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            log.error(ex);
        }

        // Mongodb connection string.
        String client_url = "mongodb://" + auth_user + ":" + encoded_pwd + "@" + host_name + ":" + port_no + "/" + db_name;
        MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(client_url);

        // Connecting to the mongodb server using the given client uri.
        MongoClient mongo_client = new MongoClient(uri);

        // Fetching the database from the mongodb.
        MongoDatabase db = mongo_client.getDatabase(db_name);

        // Fetching the collection from the mongodb.
        MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection(db_col_name);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is using the MongoDB Java driver version 3.12:

```
try(MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017/")) {

    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
    Document collStatsResults = db.runCommand(new Document("collStats", "myCollection"));
    System.out.println(collStatsResults.get("size"));
    System.out.println(collStatsResults.get("storageSize"));
}
```

Note the usage of the `try-with-resources` clause; it closes the `MongoClient` object after its use to release the connection related resources.